# Using HttpClient Post for elasticSearch Request Body Search

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, httpclient

I am using HttpClient for elasticSearch in java, as the official document says there are two ways: using a simple query string as a parameter, or using a request body.

When i using Request Body Search. if using curl, it would be:

```
curl -XGET 'http://192.168.11.131:9200/docmanager/user/_search' -d '{
    "query":{
        "term":{"userName":"account"}
    }
}
```

So i create the json string

```
{"query":{"term":{"userName":"account"}}}
```

and use HttpPost() in Apache HttpClient, the code is as follows:

```
    public List<Map<String, Object>> search(String index, String type,String filterString,
        QueryBuilder builder) {
    String searchUri="http://"+mMasterNodeUrl+":"+mMasterNodePort+"/"+index+"/"+type
    +"/_search";
    StringEntity filter=new StringEntity(filterString, "UTF-8");
    filter.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
    JsonNode rootJsonNode=sendHttpPost(searchUri, filter);
```

here `filterString` is the json query string i create

```
    private JsonNode sendHttpPost(String uri,StringEntity args){
    HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(uri);
    if(args!=null)
        httpPost.setEntity(args);
    HttpClientContext clientContext=createBasicAuthContext(mEsAdminName, mEsAdminPassowrd);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient=HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse=null;
    try {
        httpResponse=httpClient.execute(mMasterNodeHttpHost, httpPost, clientContext);
```

It works.
However, when i want to do something like multi-conditions search like https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-filter-context.html

```
{"query":
    {"bool":
        {"must":[
            {"match":{"name":"test1"}},
            {"match":{"content":"some contents"}}],
         "filter":[
            {"range":{"date":{"to":"1448957966693"}}},
            {"range":{"level":{"from":"1","to":"2"}}}]
         }
     }
 }
```

I pass the above json string into method `List<Map<String, Object>> search(String index, String type,String filterString,QueryBuilder builder)`

Error happens, the error from `httpResponse` is:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"docmanager","node":"Gk5r4QaXQnar95GalR6anA","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}}]},"status":400}
```

It seems the json string can not be parsed? But why it works in the first condition?

Update

the error message in elasticsearch.log is:

```
[2015-12-01 21:53:33,643][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [ezio] [docmanager][3], node[PZrESgD8TeSMUgTzJna12g], [P], v[32], s[STARTED], a[id=WBcMBH19SDG7cYpb6SCOUg]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@1dce9d35] lastShard [true]
RemoteTransportException[[ezio][192.168.123.6:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [_na_]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent];
Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [_na_]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent];
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:860)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:663)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:632)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:374)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.transport.ShieldServerTransportService$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(ShieldServerTransportService.java:165)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.xContent(XContentFactory.java:293)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:829)
    ... 11 more
```

By the way, the json string is created manully, does it matter?

Comment: What version of ES are you running?

Comment: The ES version is 2.0

Comment: Have you found a solution so far?

Comment: @7twenty7 Sorry, still no answer.